# Is VS 2010 needed to build a SharePoint 2010 project in Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, powershell

Can you build a SharePoint Project without Visual Studio 2010/2012 being installed on the machine you are trying build it on using PowerShell?

I have a PowerShell script the is working great. It calls up SlikSVN hits my repository checks the code I want out and builds it using MSBuild.exe. Granted that this machine has Visual Studio 2012 installed on it and SharePoint Foundation 2010 as well. When I try to run the script on a machine with just SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed I get a few errors. I was able to suppress some by copying varying folders and files over, but now I am stuck with an error I cannot resolve.

Error in powershell:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(4
>       80,5): error MSB4066: The attribute "BeforeTargets" in element  is unrecognized.

After I installed the .Net 4 Framework and Win SDK I get this error. I cannot remember if I copied this folder:
(C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools) from my Dev machine or not. It seems like I need to some how register the DLLs but I tried Regsvr32.exe with no luck.

Updated error:

```
    C:\Program Files\(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(3
    52,5): error MSB4062: The "SetPackagingProperties" task could not be loaded from
    the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MS Build\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\
    SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks.dll.
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Tasks,
    Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT:
    0x8013141A) Confirm that the <Using Task> declaration is correct, that the assembly
    and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
    that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to install is the .NET Framework SDK, not only the client profile. For more info check the following Stack Overflow answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558138/net-framework-installation-include-msbuild

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567018/installing-msbuild-4-0-without-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I will give this a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks